# How to get record form table has different column value and same foreign key?

Tags: php, joomla, database-connection

I have three tables named:

1. `orders`,
2. `orderitems`
3. `orderitemattributes`

I need to get the record where `orderitemattribute_name = "OPTION_DATE"` and `orderitemattribute_value = "01-09-2018"` and `orderitemattribute_name = "OPTION_SIZE"`;

Single `orderitems` has many `orderitemattributes` records like: `OPTION_DATE`,`OPTION_SIZE`

```
$rentaldateconstant="OPTION_DATE";

$todaydate="01-09-2018";

$shoesize="OPTION_SIZE";

$query = JFactory::getDbo()->getQuery(true);
$query->select('oi.orderitem_id,oi.orderitem_name,oi.product_id,oi.orderitem_quantity');
$query->select('oi.order_id');
$query->select('oia.orderitemattribute_name,oia.orderitemattribute_value');
$query->from('#__orders AS jo');
$query->leftJoin('#__orderitems AS oi ON oi.order_id=jo.order_id');
$query->leftJoin('#__orderitemattributes AS oia ON oia.orderitem_id=oi.orderitem_id');
$query->where('oia.orderitemattribute_name = '.$db->Quote($rentaldateconstant).' AND oia.orderitemattribute_value ='.$db->Quote($todaydate));
$query->orwhere('oia.orderitemattribute_name = '.$db->Quote($shoesize));
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you didn't store your connection object (`JFactory::getDbo()`).  I'll include a complete `try-catch` block to show you some best practice coding which will save you lots of time in the future when debugging is necessary.

Had you written code to catch errors you would have been presented with:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function Quote() on null

In other words `$db` was not defined and was `null`.  This means `quote()` didn't have a resource to operate from.

Suggested/Untested Code:

```
$rentaldateconstant="OPTION_DATE";
$todaydate="01-09-2018";
$shoesize="OPTION_SIZE";

$db = JFactory::getDbo();       // you should call this once and use the variable when needed
try {
    $query = $db->getQuery(true)
                ->select(
                      array(
                          "oi.orderitem_id",
                          "oi.orderitem_name",
                          "oi.product_id",
                          "oi.orderitem_quantity",
                          "oi.order_id",
                          "oia.orderitemattribute_name",
                          "oia.orderitemattribute_value"
                      )
                  )
                ->from("#__orders AS jo")
                ->leftJoin("#__orderitems AS oi ON oi.order_id=jo.order_id"
                ->leftJoin("#__orderitemattributes AS oia ON oia.orderitem_id=oi.orderitem_id"
                ->where("oia.orderitemattribute_name = " . $db->q($rentaldateconstant) . " AND oia.orderitemattribute_value = " . $db->q($todaydate))
                ->orwhere("oia.orderitemattribute_name = " . $db->q($shoesize));
    echo $query->dump();  // to see what you've generated (never show to public)
    $db->setQuery($query);
    var_export($db->loadObjectList());  // to see what your resultset looks like as an array of objects
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Syntax Error " , $e->getMessage();   // never show exact error details to public
}
```

---

I also want to question your `WHERE` clause logic.  I don't know what your project logic requires, but this is the generated clause from your query:

> (oia.orderitemattribute_name = 'OPTION_DATE' AND
>   oia.orderitemattribute_value ='01-09-2018') OR 
>   (oia.orderitemattribute_name = 'OPTION_SIZE')

However, I think your goal is to glue the conditions together with `AND`.

```
->where(
      array(
          "oia.orderitemattribute_name = " . $db->q($rentaldateconstant),
          "oia.orderitemattribute_value = " . $db->q($todaydate),
          "oia.orderitemattribute_name = " . $db->q($shoesize)
      )
  )
```

this generates:

```
WHERE oia.orderitemattribute_name = 'OPTION_DATE'
  AND oia.orderitemattribute_value = '01-09-2018'
  AND oia.orderitemattribute_name = 'OPTION_SIZE'
```

Finally, a small piece of advice...  When saving date values to a database, I recommend using a DATE type column and store the values as `YYYY-MM-DD` so that you can more easily query/manipulate the data in the future.

Comment: If my answer doesn't fully solve the issue, I'll ask you to prepare an sqlfiddle demo with the required tables (and just enough data to test with) so that I can make further adjustments.